# Springboot test controller via WebClient instead of WebTestClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-webclient

I'm attempting something perhaps misguided but please help.

I would like to test springboot controller via `@WebFluxTest`. However I would like to use `WebClient` instead of `WebTestClient`. How can this be done?

So far, I managed to use reflection to get `ExchangeFunction` out of WebTestClient and assign it to WebClient - and it works! Calls are made, controller responds - wonderful. However I don't think this is good approach. Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `WebTestClient` which is designed for testing?

Comment: Long story very short: internally we build and include clients with a service. Client should be tested as well. Integration testing is not an option at the moment (pipeline doesn't allow for it). 

P.S: we used to use DropWizard framework and above scenario was easily accomplished in 2 lines of code.

Comment: Use the `WebClient.Builder` to create one and use the auto-config of spring boot. I still don't see why what you want to do cannot be accomplished with `WebTestClient` which is just a wrapper around the `WebClient`.

Comment: @M. Deinum, do you mind throwing example together. I'm new to Spring & Springboot. Currently migrating service from Dropwizard to Springboot.

Comment: P.S: I would be happy to discuss the issue further in private. Let me know if your curiosity prevails.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use a `WebTestClient` which is more of a convenience wrapper around the `WebClient`. Just like the `TestRestTemplate` is for a `RestTemplate`. Both allow a request to be created and you can easily make assertions. They exist to make your test life easier.

If you really want to use a `WebClient` instead of a `WebTestClient` and do the assertions manually (which means you are probably complicating things) you can use the `WebClient.Builder` to create one. Spring Boot will automatically configure one and you can simply autowire it in your test and call the `build` method.

```
@SpringBootTest
public void YourTest {
  
  @Autowired
  private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

  @Test
  public void doTest() {
    WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

The same should work with `@WebFluxTest` as well.

Comment: using `@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)` I'm encountering issue: 
`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webClientBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder`

Comment: I also wondering is WebTestClient actually uses WebClient? WebTestClient looks very similar to WebClient but all of the interfaces are different. It looks like code has been copied and assertions added for convenience.

Comment: Nothing has been copied, it delegates to the WebClient and adds assertions. You can add @Import(WebClientAutoConfiguration) for the autoconfiguration, I wrongly assumed that that was part of the @WebFluxTest.

Comment: It is still trying to access port 80:
`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:80; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:80

 at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
`

Comment: Spring version: 5.3.9 & Springboot version: 2.5.3

Comment: The `WebClient` will obviously connect to a real URL, when using the `WebTestClient` it will use a mocked infrastructure and will not connect to a regular host.

Comment: Here is a short explanation and reasoning to the question: "why?" - https://meirz.net/2021/09/02/springboot-test-custom-client-controllers-and-or-filters-a-quick-way/

Comment: I posted working example of a solution. However I didn't quite answer my own question - since I was asking about `@WebFluxTest` and NOT `@WebMvcTest`.

Comment: Now your "answer" contains something very important that you kept out of your question. You nowhere mentioned or explained that the `WebClient` is an actual dependency of your client. Now that was quite a crucial part of the whole question and which would lead to a different answer. Nonetheless it wouldn't work with `@WebFluxTest` as it isn't a test for a controller but rather for the client (the same applies to `@WebMvcTest` and hence all the work you  need to do to make it work).

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry about this. I was a bit panicky and didn't formulate the question well. Lesson learned, next time I'll do better. Thank you for all your effort, it helped to arrive at the solution! I'm grateful.

Comment: I would like to mention, that I used your solution initially with a twist. I took `WebTestClient` - extracted `ExchangeFunction` via reflection and set the function to WebClient and set it to my custom client (`subject.setWebClient(webClient);). The test actually worked! Controller was receiving and responding :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much experimentation here is a solution to test springboot controller & filters via a mocked connection - no webservice, no ports and quick test.

Unfortunately I didn't work out how to do it via `@WebFluxTest` and `WebClient`, instead `MockMvc` can be used to achieve desired result:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import({SomeDependencyService.class, SomeFilter.class})
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc()
public class SomeControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private SomeDependencyService someDependencyService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private SomeCustomizedClient subject;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        subject = buildClient();

        WebClient webClient = mockClientConnection();
        subject.setWebClient(webClient);
    }

    private WebClient mockClientConnection() {
        MockMvcHttpConnector mockMvcHttpConnector = new MockMvcHttpConnector(mockMvc);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(mockMvcHttpConnector).build();
        return webClient;
    }

    @Test
    public void sample() {
        when(SomeDependencyService.somePersistentOperation(any(), any())).thenReturn(new someDummyData());

        SomeDeserializedObject actual = subject.someCallToControllerEndpoint("example param");

        assertThat(actual.getData).isEquals("expected data");
    }

}
```

Now it is possible to test your customized client (for example if you have internal java client that contains few important customization like security, etags, logging, de-serialization and uniform error handling) and associated controller (and filters if you `@import` them along) at the cost of a unit test.

You do NOT have to bring up entire service to verify the client and controller is working correctly.